# Loop trough array, select chunk and skip every x Th?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 ,3...]
```

Every first three elements/chunks in array describes X Y Z position
I need to loop trough it and check if every Y is not more than `2`

If its not, we push every 10th to new array, I believe it should be something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    /* SELECING EVERY THREE */
    if (/* SELECTED[1] (Y coord) */ < 2) {
        // Checking if we skipped 9 chunks so we push 10th?
        newArray.push(/* 10th */);
    }
}
```

I hope the explanation was clear enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not an array. Arrays are surrounded by `[]`, `{}` is used for objects.

Comment: do you have some examples and results?

Comment: Why every 10th? And every 10th element in the array or every 10th set of coordinates?

Comment: Expected results please

Answer (score 1):

Increment your index by 3 instead of 1 each time through the loop.

You can't tell if *every* element matched a condition until you get to the end of a chunk. Use a variable that you update during the loop, and check at the end of each chunk.

```
let all_lessthan_2 = true;
for (let i = 1, chunks = 0; i < array.length; i += 3, chunks++) {
    if (selected[i] > 2) {
        all_lessthan_2 = false;
    }
    if (chunks == 10) {
        if (all_lessthan_2) {
            newArray.push(selected[i]);
        }
        chunks = 0;
        all_lessthan_2 = true;
    }
}
```